# User creation with IdentityServer4 from multiple API's

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

So I have been bashing my head for a while with this problem.

We have one web app that is using **IdentityServer4** and **AspNetIdentity** to authenticate and register users (*this is working as intended*). 
In addition, we have an other API (inside the same solution) **that is able to use IdentityServer4 to authenticate users accessing the API**.

However, the problem is, that besides authentication we cannot use the API to **create new users**.

For instance, users should be able to create other users through the web API and not only from the web app, because in our case, users are linked to other users (think of it as multiple profiles).

I am not really familiar with all the configuration services that come up with .Net Core framework and I have tried multiple ways of accessing the user manager of the web app through the API to register my users through classic POST requests but nothing seems to be working. Searching online is tricky because our problem is kind of very specific, that's why I am posting here.

*API Startup.cs - ConfigureServices:*

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
     // base-address of your identityserver
     options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServer:Url"];

     // name of the API resource
     options.ApiName = Configuration["IdentityServer:APIName"];
     options.ApiSecret = Configuration["IdentityServer:APISecret"];

     options.EnableCaching = true;
     options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // that's the default

     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["IdentityServer:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
});
```

*API Startup.cs - Configure:*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

*API UsersController.cs - Constructor:*

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public UsersController(IUserService service,
ApplicationDbContext context,
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _service = service;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _context = context;
}
```

Now the problem is that when I start the API and try to access the UsersController I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[XXXXX.Data.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'XXXXXXX.Api.Controllers.UsersController'.
```

I sincerely hope I can find at least some advice on how to proceed with it.

Please if something is unclear reply and I will be more than happy to add more information or make things clear.

Kind regards,

Marios.

***EDIT:***
Thanks all for replying. The code snippet provided below by @Vidmantas did the trick.

Due to my limited knowledge of .net core I did a lot of trial and error in the configure services function which, as you can imagine, didn't work. I strongly believe that using .net core is kind of easy (e.g. API), but when it comes to configuring services the complexity (puzzling/confusing mostly) explodes.

As for the architecture, you gave me good ideas for future refactoring. Notes taken.

Marios.

Comment: You are trying to dynamically modify the configuration file of the project.  Am I correct?  The clients probably do not have the permission to modify files on the Server.   I it probably better to create a database with the configuration data rather than to modify the configuration file.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean. The clients already can modify the database through the API by doing all sorts of requests as specified in the policies. However, what they cannot achieve is to create a new user as their "profile". Thanks

Comment: there are several problems going on. Did you register UserManager in services in the api? even if you did, mot likely the AppicationUser and relevant migrations live in a different app than the api. You would need to move that stuff into a shared class library to use it in a separate api app.

Comment: Yes I did register the UserManager. The thing is, that both projects reference the same DataAccess project which lies as well into the same solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you are not really supposed to create users through the API - that is why you have Identity Server 4 in place - to provide central authority for authentication for your user base. What you actually need:

- a set of API endpoints on the Identity Server 4 side to manage AspNetIdentity
- completely new API but one that shares the same database with Identity Server 4 for your AspNetIdentity
- have your API share the database for AspNet Identity

If you go with the last option then you probably need something like below to add the:

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(); //make sure it's same database as IdentityServer4

services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => { });
new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUser), typeof(IdentityRole), services)
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();
```

This will give you enough services to use the `UserManager` and it won't set up any unnecessary authentication schemes.

I would not recommend the last approach due to the separation of concerns - your API should be concerned about providing resources, not creating users and providing resources. First and second approach are alright in my opinion, but I would always lean for clean separate service for AspNetIdentity management.

An example architecture from one of my projects where we implemented such approach:

- auth.somedomain.com - IdentityServer4 web app with AspNetIdentity for user authentication.
- accounts.somedomain.com - AspNetCore web app with AspNetIdentity (same database as Identity Server 4) for AspNetIdentity user management
- webapp1.somedomain.com - a web app where all your front end logic resides (can ofcourse have a backend as well if AspNetCore MVC or something like that)
- api1.somedomain.com - a web app purely for API purposes (if you go single app for front end and backend then you can combine the last two)

Comment: Well, what happens is that users can have, and controll other "sub-users" as I mentioned already. So think of this. The first web app which adds the IdentityServer4 is is the one that is used for authentication and the initial registration. This is also separated because you can add your own API and authenticate with us. Then, through the other API you can add sub-users that you as a main user can control. The creation of sub-users should be the same via the same UserManager, with the difference that they are linked into another table as sub-users.

Comment: So what you propose is maybe a good idea for refactoring the existing projects and thinking of a better architecture in general, but I am not sure if it complies with the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.If you have appropriately modeled your `ApplicationUser` to allow the schema to reflect the business need to have linked users then you only need to use the same `IdentityDbContext` and same `ApplicationUser` in both web apps and the rest should work out of the box. I supplied code snippet for that as well in my answer to get you going on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code snippet you provided is working and I can add new users now through the API.

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar situation as you do.

- Identity server with asp .net identity users. (DB contains clients and user data)
- API (database contains access to application data)  .net Framework
- Application .net Framework.

Our use case was that normally new users would be created though the identity server.  However we also wanted the ability for the application to invite users.   So i could be logged into the application and i wanted to invite my friend.  The idea was that the invite would act the same as if a user was creating themselves.

So it would send an email to my friend with a code attached and the user would then be able to supply their password and have an account.

To do this i created a new action on my account controller.

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Invited([FromQuery] InviteUserRequest request)
    {

        if (request.Code == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(request.UserId.ToString());
        if (user == null)
         {
          return View("Error");
        }

        var validateCode = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, _userManager.Options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider, "ResetPassword", Uri.UnescapeDataString(request.Code));
        if (!validateCode)
        {
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login), new { message = ManageMessageId.PasswordResetFailedError, messageAttachment = "Invalid code." });
        }

        await _userManager.EnsureEmailConfirmedAsync(user);
        await _userManager.EnsureLegacyNotSetAsync(user);

        return View(new InvitedViewModel { Error = string.Empty, Email = user.Email, Code = request.Code, UserId = user.Id });
    }
```

When the user accepts the email we add them.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Invited([FromForm] InvitedViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Error = "invalid model";
            return View(model);
        }

        if (!model.Password.Equals(model.ConfirmPassword))
        {

            model.Error = "Passwords must match";
            return View(model);
        }
        if (model.Terms != null && !model.Terms.All(t => t.Accept))
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {             
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login), new { message = ManageMessageId.InvitedFailedError, messageAttachment = "User Not invited please invite user again." });
        }

        var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, Uri.UnescapeDataString(model.Code), model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {            
            return Redirect(_settings.Settings.XenaPath);
        }

        var errors = AddErrors(result);
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login), new { message = ManageMessageId.InvitedFailedError, messageAttachment = errors });
    }
```

The reason for doing it this way is that only the identity server should be reading and writing to its database.  The api and the third party applications should never need to directly change the database controlled by another application.   so in this manner the API tells the identity server to invite a user and then the identity server controls everything else itself.

Also by doing it this way it removes your need for having the user manager in your API :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, even though your reply is relevant, it does not answer my exact question, based on the current situation and architecture. You provide a solution for an alternative way of "doing" things, which may be interesting when refactoring kicks in. So I am going to upvote you but I will as an answer the one above.

Comment: @Davelis4 i can live with that. I knew it wasn't exactly what you where after but thought it might be worth giving it to you.

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend you to use shared database between different API's.
If you need to extend Identity Server 4 with additional API you can use [LocalApiAuthentication](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html) for your controllers.