# Use of ConfigurationDbContext in IndetityServer4 from different API's

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

After solving my initial problem with adding UserManager to an API ([User creation with IdentityServer4 from multiple API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493921/user-creation-with-identityserver4-from-multiple-apis/54515377?noredirect=1#comment95863315_54515377)) that does not initialize IdentityServer4  (which in turn is initialized inside a web app only responsible for registration and login of users) I have run to another problem. From the same API I wish to also get the Clients and Resources from the IConfigurationDbContext of IdentityServer4.

What I am trying so far is the following: 
I am adding the ConfigurationDbContext in the startup of the API and then through the ClientsController and ClientsRepository I am trying to access the clients as shown below.

*Startup.cs*

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(defaultConnection, db => db.MigrationsAssembly("XXXXXXX"))
    );

 services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(defaultConnection, db => db.MigrationsAssembly("XXXXXXXX"))
    );

  services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => {
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    });
    new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUser), typeof(IdentityRole), services)
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

*ClientsRepository.cs* (in .DataAccess):

```
private readonly IConfigurationDbContext _context;
public bool AutoSaveChanges { get; set; } = true;

public ClientRepository(IConfigurationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public Task<Client> GetClientAsync(int id)
{
    return _context.Clients
        .Include(x => x.AllowedGrantTypes)
        .Include(x => x.RedirectUris)
        .Include(x => x.PostLogoutRedirectUris)
        .Include(x => x.AllowedScopes)
        .Include(x => x.ClientSecrets)
        .Include(x => x.Claims)
        .Include(x => x.IdentityProviderRestrictions)
        .Include(x => x.AllowedCorsOrigins)
        .Include(x => x.Properties)
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
 }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Interfaces.IConfigurationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'XXXXXX.Data.Repositories.ClientRepository'.
```

I am guessing it has again to do something with the services Startup, but I cannot seem to find it.

Has anyone solved something similar?

Best,
Marios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the `ServicesCollection` extensions that are already in the IDS4.EFCore package if you want to use these:

```
        services.AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseNpgsql(defaultConnection, db => db.MigrationsAssembly("XXXXXXXX"));
        });
```

This will add you the `IConfigurationDbContext` so that it can later be used in other services through DI.

Use the below static methods if you want to add it directly to the `ServicesCollection`:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddConfigurationStore(this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<ConfigurationStoreOptions> storeOptionsAction = null)
    {
        return services.AddConfigurationStore<ConfigurationDbContext>(storeOptionsAction);
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddConfigurationStore<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<ConfigurationStoreOptions> storeOptionsAction = null)
    where TContext : DbContext, IConfigurationDbContext
    {
        var options = new ConfigurationStoreOptions();
        services.AddSingleton(options);
        storeOptionsAction?.Invoke(options);

        if (options.ResolveDbContextOptions != null)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TContext>(options.ResolveDbContextOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TContext>(dbCtxBuilder =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext?.Invoke(dbCtxBuilder);
            });
        }
        services.AddScoped<IConfigurationDbContext, TContext>();

        return services;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have any method AddConfigurationDbContext, are you sure it is like this? As you can see in my startup I used the AddDbContext with ConfigurationDbContext but it does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Davelis4 where is `ConfiguratonDbContext` declared? Which assembly i mean.Also, I've edited the answer, I was slightly wrong in the method name. It is `AddConfigurationStore` afterall.

Comment: The ConfigurationDbContext is declared as in my previous question in the WebApp and not in the API that I am trying to access it from. In addition, AddConfigurationStore throws the following: IServiceCollection does not a contain a definition for ... and the best extension method overload IdentityServerEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.AddConfigurationStore(...) requires a receiver of type 'IIdentityServerBuilder;'

Comment: @Davelis4 Ok fair enough, I gave you more code to make this work directly with `ServicesCollection`. Create some extension class to hold these static methods.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. Have to ask though, whats the main difference? Because In my startup I did something similar by adding ConfigureDbContext as AddDbContext but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Something I forgot to ask, does this work the same for Resources except clients? Have you tried it before? Thanks again.

Comment: @Davelis4 yeah this will work for querying api resources as welll through the context. And to answer your other question, your version of this didn’t work because you were adding a concrete type of ConfigurationDbContext but then you were trying to use the interface version in your controller.

Comment: I am using multi tenant application , so how to configure configuration store based on tenant db credentials?