# Managing IdentityServerv4 using APIs

Tags: api, identityserver4

I know that it is possible to manage IdentityServerv4 clients registration using AdminUI. However, I'd like to manage these registrations using APIs, is it possible?

Comment: I think that is a lack of information about this subject, maybe this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493921/user-creation-with-identityserver4-from-multiple-apis) or this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450840/user-registration-process-with-identityserver4) maybe be useful for you

Comment: Can you clarify further? What I need to do is to create clients dynamically using APIs. This example should how to create a client with a client id and client secret in a hard coded manner ( https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html ) I want to do something similar but using an API rather than hard-coding it

Comment: Have you considered to use the device flow? https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/services/device_flow_interaction_service/